# get qty ordered when there is promotion rules

Tags: magento-1.7

I've got promotion rule which says when you buy3 time a product you get one of them free.

This is perfectly working in Magento but to communicate with a software I have to generate a XML file with orders details and the beginning of my headache...

Indeed my code is like this :

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$produits = $order->getAllItems();
foreach ($produits as $produit)
{   
    $prix = $produit->getPrice();
    $imei = $produit->getSku();
    $quantite = $produit->getQtyOrdered();
    $product_attribut = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($produit->getId());
    $xml_product = $xml_products->appendChild($xml->createElement("item"));
    $xml_product->appendChild($xml->createElement("num_commande", $id_commande));
    $xml_product->appendChild($xml->createElement("products_model", $imei));
    $xml_product->appendChild($xml->createElement("price_final_unitaire", $prix));
    $xml_product->appendChild($xml->createElement("products_quantity", $quantite));
}
```

When I buy the product with the promotion rule (3 bought 1 free) Here is what I get :

```
    <item><num_commande>WR100000024</num_commande>
<products_model>XPERIAZW</products_model>
<price_final_unitaire>395.0000</price_final_unitaire>
<products_quantity>3.0000</products_quantity></item><item>
<num_commande>WR100000024</num_commande>
<products_model>XPERIAZW</products_model>
<price_final_unitaire>0.0000</price_final_unitaire>
<products_quantity>3.0000</products_quantity></item>
```

As you can see I've 2 lines for the same product One is at 0 and the other on the right price (395). However the quantity is the same for the 2 lines. That's mean 6 products : 3 at 395 and 3 at 0 instead of 2 at 395 and 1 at 0.

Hope it's clear! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is related to the promotional code. Is your product a configurable product? This would explain the results since both the configurable and simple product are added to the order. The simple products have a 0 value. I think it might solve this if you use `$order->getAllVisibleItems()`. Alternatively you can loop through all products and do something like:

```
// at the top of the loop skip simple products (price is on configurable).
if ($produit->getParentItem()) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: You are right. It's a problem with configurable product.